# How to validate sharepoint datetime control?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, validation

I am using sharepoint datetime control, and when i use range,regular or some other validation controls, every time error message will show up when input wrong format (this is right), but after that when i input right date, this error message won't disappear, it stays there, can't remove... (problem happened)

Is there any other way like javascript to validate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Display="Dynamic" for the validation control.